# Invalid value specified for connection string attribute

Tags: python, sql-server, pycharm, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc as po    

connection_string = """
driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;
server=SHADOW-LN4F5NUO;
database=FBI_Crime_Data;
trusted_connection=True;
"""

connection = po.connect(connection_string)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\GitHub\FBI_Crime_Data_Analysis\main.py", line 133, in <module>
    import_file(file_location="data/ASR122016.TXT")
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\GitHub\FBI_Crime_Data_Analysis\main.py", line 122, in import_file
    export_dataframe_to_SQL_Server(df=df, table_name=table_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\GitHub\FBI_Crime_Data_Analysis\main.py", line 40, in export_dataframe_to_SQL_Server
    connection = po.connect(connection_string)
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'trusted_connection' (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

- Server name is correct.
- Database name is correct
- ODBC driver exists.
- Windows Authentication in SSMS works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8), recognized values are `true`, `false`, `yes`, `no`, and `sspi`

[pyodbc documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows#other-connection-attributes) says, you can use your Windows account for authentication instead of username/password by providing Trusted_Connection attribute as: `Trusted_Connection=yes`

So it looks the [connectionstrings sql server main page](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) shows you the connection string for .Net libraries. If you click on any of the pages for a specific version of the driver under "ODBC drivers" (like [17](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server/) or [13](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-13-for-sql-server/) or [11](https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server/)), it shows `Trusted_Connection=yes`

Comment: I don't think capitalization matters, but `yes` worked. `true` and `sspi` didn't work. Any idea why that may be the case? Does it depend on the SQL Server version?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I know the problem now. It's not really a typo, just terrible, confusing web design. See this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/VX43VWX.png

Comment: What's worse, the URL just says https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/. Not even telling you that you're viewing a connection string for .Net

Comment: Good catch! I updated my answer to include your finding.

Answer (score 0):

```
For [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] driver
It should be like 
connection_string = "
driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;
server=SHADOW-LN4F5NUO;
database=FBI_Crime_Data;
trusted_connection=yes;
"""

For [SQL SERVER DRIVER]
It should be like :

connection_string = "
driver=SQL SERVER DRIVER;
server=SHADOW-LN4F5NUO;
database=FBI_Crime_Data;
trusted_connection=True;
"
```